# HapiJS JSON Formatting

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm writing a small CRUD app and I'd like to have some formatting on the JSON responses I'm getting (mostly for ease of reading).

Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging some more through the API documentation (RTFM, right?), I found the actual setting that enables the behavior I was looking for.

```
server.connection({
    port: 3000,
    routes: {
        json: {
            space: 4
        }
    }
});
```

While the Chrome extension is a good answer, this will work with other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend forcing your API consumers to have a pretty JSON format. If you want to see the JSON in a nice format I'd recommend installing the [Chrome JSON Formatter Plugin](https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter) or using something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: Thanks! The Chrome extension is exactly was I was looking for. I highly doubt there will by anyone other than myself consuming the API :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the pretty JSON format dynamically, based on a query param or header, you can use the following code (tested in v20.2.2):

```
srv.ext('onPreResponse', (req : Request, h : ResponseToolkit) => {
    const { response } : any = req;
    if (req.query._pretty) {
        response.spaces(2).takeover();
    }            
    return h.continue;
    });
```

If you call whatever method with a paramlike `_pretty`for instance:

```bash
curl -XGET http://localhost:3003/api/foo?_pretty=1
```

You'll get a response like:

```json
{
  "id": 1253,
  "name": "Everything OK"
}
```

But if you don't add the param:

```bash
curl -XGET http://localhost:3003/api/foo
```

Then the JSON output is collapsed:

```json
{"id":1253,"name":"Everything OK"}
```

The name of the parameter could be whatever thing that won't be used in your app, so add a prefix like `_` or whatever else, you can also use a specific header instead a query param if you prefer.